# EVM parameter Source

Tags: ethereum, solidity, substrate, evm, pallet

I'm new at substrate and pallets. I have installed the frontier node ([Frontier](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier)) and I need to use pallet_evm to upload smart contracts at the blockchain.
The function create have 6 parameters (Source, Init, Value, Gas_limit, Gas_price and Nonce).
What am I supose to put at the Source parameter?